# Defining clothing styles for simple products to belong together

Tags: magento-1.7

I just started to play around a bit with Magento to see if I can transfer one of our client's old B2B data (from Microsoft AX) into a Magento store.

Now I made a new attribute set with the name *Clothes* which holds some extra information like Color and Size.

Now the customer has products that in different colors and sizes, which they call *styles*.

I wonder what the best method is to define that "style" in Magento.

So;

Jacket A

- Size 10/16
- Color Deep Blue

Jacket A

- Size 22/28
- Color Scarlet Red

Jacket B

- Size 10/16
- Color Grass Green

.. etc.

It didn't seem that Bundles or Grouped items are fitting in the case, as they don't sell in pairs. I just want to define one *main Product* that has different *Color/Size* combinations.

Answer (score 0):

Try using configurable product.
Configurable product is the one you want

http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/tutorial-creating-a-configurable-product

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Except configurable products also cause hosting issues due to the number of products you have in the system, one per size/colour combination. It is the most common method, but there are knock-on effects of doing it, one is heavy maintenance overhead.